# Entity Framework Core - Mapping many-to-many with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper, entity-framework-core

I'm unable to create correct mappings between DAO and DTO objects with many-to-many relations using AutoMapper.
Now I could map these many-to-many properties but the other ones were null.

What is the correct mapping? I see that models' attributes have the same name and type. 
Also I'm trying to create the mapping between the parent models "ClaseFabricante" and "ClaseConstructor". Should I make it with the child ones which are many-to-many related "ReferenciaFabricante" and "ReferenciaConstructor" with ForMember()?

Entities:

```
[Table("ReferenciasFabricante", Schema = "public")]
public class ReferenciaFabricante
{

    public string NombreFabricante { get; set; }

    public string RefFabricanteIA { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ReferenciaFabricante")]
    public virtual ClaseFabricante Clase { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ReferenciaFabricante")]
    public virtual IList<ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor> MontaReferenciasConstructor { get; set; }

}

[Table("ReferenciasConstructor", Schema = "public")]
public class ReferenciaConstructor
{

    public string Referencia { get; set; }

    public string NombreConstructor { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ReferenciaConstructor")]
    public virtual ClaseConstructor Clase { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ReferenciaConstructor")]
    public virtual IList<ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor> MontadaPorReferenciasFabricante { get; set; }

}

[Table("ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor", Schema = "public")]
public class ReferenciaFabricanteTieneReferenciaConstructor {

    [Key]
    public int IdReferenciaFabricante { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdReferenciaFabricante")]
    public ReferenciaFabricante ReferenciaFabricante { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int IdReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdReferenciaConstructor")]
    public ReferenciaConstructor ReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }
}

[Table("ClasesFabricante", Schema = "public")]
public class ClaseFabricante
{

    public int? IdReferenciaFabricante { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdReferenciaFabricante")]
    public ReferenciaFabricante ReferenciaFabricante { get; set; }

}

[Table("ClasesConstructor", Schema = "public")]
public class ClaseConstructor
{

    public int? IdReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdReferenciaConstructor")]
    public ReferenciaConstructor ReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }

}
```

ViewModels:

```
public class ReferenciaFabricante {

    public string NombreFabricante { get; set; }

    public string RefFabricanteIA { get; set; }

    public virtual ClaseFabricante Clase { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ReferenciaConstructor> ReferenciasConstructor { get; set; }
}

public class ReferenciaConstructor {

    public string Referencia { get; set; }

    public string NombreConstructor { get; set; }

    public virtual ClaseConstructor Clase { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ReferenciaFabricante> ReferenciasFabricante { get; set; }
}

public class ClaseFabricante {

    public ReferenciaFabricante ReferenciaFabricante { get; set; }

}

public class ClaseConstructor {

    public ReferenciaConstructor ReferenciaConstructor { get; set; }

}
```

Mapper initialization:

```
Mapper.Initialize((config) => {

    config.CreateMap<ApplicationCore.Entities.ReferenciaFabricante, ApplicationCore.ViewModels.ReferenciaFabricante>()
    ;

    config.CreateMap<ApplicationCore.Entities.ReferenciaConstructor, ApplicationCore.ViewModels.ReferenciaConstructor>()
    ;

    config.CreateMap<ApplicationCore.Entities.ClaseFabricante, ApplicationCore.ViewModels.ClaseFabricante>()
            .ForPath(dto => dto.ReferenciaFabricante.ReferenciasConstructor, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.ReferenciaFabricante.MontaReferenciasConstructor.Select(y => y.ReferenciaConstructor).ToList()))
            .ForPath(dto => dto.ReferenciaFabricante.VersionesVehiculo, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.ReferenciaFabricante.MontaVersionesVehiculo.Select(y => y.VersionVehiculo).ToList()))
    ;

    config.CreateMap<ApplicationCore.Entities.ClaseConstructor, ApplicationCore.ViewModels.ClaseConstructor>()
            .ForPath(dto => dto.ReferenciaConstructor.ReferenciasFabricante, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.ReferenciaConstructor.MontadaPorReferenciasFabricante.Select(y => y.ReferenciaFabricante).ToList()))                
    ;            

});
```

Code:

```
foreach (ApplicationCore.Entities.ClaseFabricante cfDAO in vClasesFabricante) {

    result.Add(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ApplicationCore.ViewModels.ClaseFabricante>(cfDAO));                                
}
```